# Bind entire table row with checkbox to reactive data value in Vue3 table

Tags: javascript, forms, binding, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 form as part of an InertiaJS app (with Laravel) that uses a text field to search the back and and return a matched list of names. I display them in a table for the users to select names, show a list of the selected items, stash them in a local data variable, and then when the form is submitted, pass it to the back end.

```
<script setup>
    import {Head, Link, useForm} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
    import TextInput from '@/Components/ping/TextInput.vue'
    import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue'
    import {Inertia} from '@inertiajs/inertia';
    import {ref, watch} from 'vue';
    import Icon from '@/Components/Icon.vue';
    import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

    const form = useForm({
        name: '',
        checkedNames: []
    });

    const props = defineProps({
        users: Object,
        filters: Object,
    })

    let search = ref('')
    let selectedNames = ref([])

    watch(search, debounce(value => {
        Inertia.get('/admin/areas/create', {search: value}, {preserveState: true, replace: true})
    }, 500));

    function reset() {
        search.value = '';
        props.users = '';
    }

    function searchUsers(search) {
        Inertia.visit('/admin/areas/create', {
            method: 'get',
            data: {search: search},
            only: ['users']
        })
    }
</script>

<script>
    import DefaultLayout from '@/Layouts/DefaultLayout.vue';

    export default {
        layout: DefaultLayout
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        
      ...
        <div v-if="search.length > 0">
            <table class="table-auto">
                <thead>
                <tr class="text-left font-bold">
                    <th class="pb-4 pt-6 px-6 text-sm">Select</th>
                    <th class="pb-4 pt-6 px-6 text-sm">Name</th>
                    <th class="pb-4 pt-6 px-6 text-sm">Last Name</th>
                    <th class="pb-4 pt-6 px-6 text-sm">Member Number</th>
                    <th class="pb-4 pt-6 px-6 text-sm">Status</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id" class="hover:bg-gray-100 focus-within:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="border-t">
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            :value="user.id"
                            v-model="selectedNames"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td class="border-t">
                        {{ user.first_name }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border-t">
                        {{ user.last_name }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border-t">
                        {{ user.member_number }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border-t">
                        {{ user.status }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-5">
            <h2 class="text-lg font-bold">Selected Approvers</h2>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="selected in selectedNames">{{ selected }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is the data in `users` as it is returned from the back end.

```
const users = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "member_number":1234,
    "first_name":"Richard",
    "last_name":"Brown",
    "email":"richard@brown.com",
    "status":"Active"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "member_number":2345,
    "first_name":"Joe",
    "last_name":"Blow",
    "email":"joe@blow.com",
    "status":"Active"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "member_number":6789,
    "first_name":"Sam",
    "last_name":"Snead",
    "email":"same@snead.com",
    "status":"Inactive"
  },
]
```

My question is, in the `Selected Approvers` list at the bottom, I want to also display the `member_number`, `first_name`, and `last_name` fields, but I'm currently only binding on the `id` column. How can I also bind on the other columns so that they are available in the `selectedNames` variable? Is there a way to a) use a checkbox as I am doing and also b) bind the entire `user` object to `selectedNames`?

Comment: I added a data set to the question, will add more in a bit.

Comment: Answer again edited. Please comment if unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to solve my problem withe a slight variation on the answer by Hovercraft above by binding the value of the entire object to the checkbox:

```
<tr v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id" class="hover:bg-gray-100 focus-within:bg-gray-100">
    <td class="border-t">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            :value="user"
            v-model="form.selectedNames"
        />
    </td>
    <td class="border-t">
        {{ user.first_name }}
    </td>
    <td class="border-t">
         {{ user.last_name }}
    </td>
    <td class="border-t">
        {{ user.member_number }}
    </td>
    <td class="border-t">
        {{ user.status }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

As pointed out by @tao, I needed `selectedNames` to outlive a more volatile users page, since this could change due to server side pagination (as compared to storing all values in the component and just paging through them).

I also had to update it to bind to `form.selectedNames`, since that is the form values that are submitted by the InertiaJS form helper.

```
const form = useForm({
    name: '',
    selectedNames: []
});
```

Comment: Sorry to offend you by not upvoting. I added a vote.

Answer (score 2):

Select the user id's and place them into a collection of these, as you are doing, and then use this array to filter the users data to show only those users that have been selected.  And so in the code example below, I am displaying the selected users (again by use of id) in its own table:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="selected in selectedUsers" :key="selected.id">
        <td>
            {{ selected.first_name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ selected.last_name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ selected.member_number }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ selected.status }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And I'm providing the data for this table via a calculated property that uses the array of user id's:

```javascript
const selectedUserIds = ref([]);
const selectedUsers = computed(() => {
    return users.value.filter((user) => selectedUserIds.value.includes(user.id));
});
```

Answer updated as per recommendations by Tao)

---

---

My MRE example is below.

You can also run my example code in the Vue SFC Playground here: [Playground link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Foo02</h2>
        <div class="clearSelected">
            <button @click="clearSelected">
                Clear All Selected
            </button>
        </div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Member Number</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" @click="toggleRow(user.id)">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" :value="user.id" v-model="selectedUserIds" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ user.first_name }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ user.last_name }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ user.member_number }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ user.status }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div>
            <h2>Selected Approvers</h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Member Number</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="selected in selectedUsers" :key="selected.id">
                        <td>
                            {{ selected.first_name }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ selected.last_name }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ selected.member_number }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ selected.status }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue';

const selectedUserIds = ref([]);
const selectedUsers = computed(() => {
    return users.value.filter((user) => selectedUserIds.value.includes(user.id));
});

const clearSelected = () => {
    selectedUserIds.value = [];
}

const toggleRow = (userId) => {
    if (selectedUserIds.value.includes(userId)) {
        selectedUserIds.value = selectedUserIds.value.filter((id) => id !== userId);
    } else {
        selectedUserIds.value.push(userId);
    }
}

const users = ref(
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "member_number": 6109,
            "first_name": "Richard",
            "last_name": "Brown",
            "email": "RBrown@fu.com",
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "member_number": 9931,
            "first_name": "Joe",
            "last_name": "Blow",
            "email": "JBlow@fu.com",
            "status": "Inactive"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "member_number": 8292,
            "first_name": "Sam",
            "last_name": "Snead",
            "email": "SSnead@fu.com",
            "status": "Inactive"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "member_number": 4741,
            "first_name": "Donald",
            "last_name": "Duck",
            "email": "DDuck@fu.com",
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "member_number": 8839,
            "first_name": "Micky",
            "last_name": "Mouse",
            "email": "MMouse@fu.com",
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "member_number": 2692,
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "email": "JDoe@fu.com",
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "member_number": 9843,
            "first_name": "George",
            "last_name": "Washington",
            "email": "GWashington@fu.com",
            "status": "Inactive"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "member_number": 6452,
            "first_name": "Abraham",
            "last_name": "Lincoln",
            "email": "ALincoln@fu.com",
            "status": "Inactive"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "member_number": 4918,
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Lennon",
            "email": "JLennon@fu.com",
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "member_number": 3459,
            "first_name": "Phil",
            "last_name": "Simms",
            "email": "PSimms@fu.com",
            "status": "Inactive"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "member_number": 2447,
            "first_name": "James",
            "last_name": "Bond",
            "email": "JBond@fu.com",
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "member_number": 2142,
            "first_name": "Bugs",
            "last_name": "Bunny",
            "email": "BBunny@fu.com",
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "member_number": 995,
            "first_name": "Fred",
            "last_name": "Flinstone",
            "email": "FFlinstone@fu.com",
            "status": "Inactive"
        }
    ]
);
</script>

<style scoped>
table {
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

th {
    padding: 5px 25px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    padding: 5px 25px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.clearSelected {
    margin: 1em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you rename `selectedNames` to `selectedUsers`? Side note: avoid copying objects. Instead, create a computed which uses an array of `ids` to filter the *"single source of truth"* (`users` in your case). Might seem more complicated, but it avoids headaches. E.g: what happens when users get updated/replaced in `users`? Now you have to keep `users` and `selectedNames` in sync. Don't go there.

Comment: Unless, of course, you want `selectedUses` to outlive a more volatile `users` page, while you build up a selection of users from multiple users pages and send it somewhere. Again, you'd only be sending `ids`, but you want to maintain the ability to render the selection's details when the initial `users` are no longer contained in the `users` array. In that case it's OK to make copies. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @tao: I have updated the answer as per your suggestions above. Please let me know if this is better. As always, your input is *greatly* appreciated!!